# What does Jetty do and do I need to activate it?

Tags: 12.04, java

What does Jetty really do? I've read a lot of info about Jetty googling but everywhere it's just a few info about it. Because once or twice I got pop up message saying:
    Not starting jetty - edit /etc/default/jetty and change NO_START to be 0
by default it is set to 1 on my system, here's the part of jetty log:

```
Defaults for jetty see /etc/init.d/jetty for more

change to 0 to allow Jetty to start
NO_START=1
```

So do I need to change it to zero or is it recommended also and what will it affect?

Comment: Jetty provides a Web server.  Did you install it?  Are you using it?

Comment: no I didn't install it manually it happened after I uninstalled Nvidia drivers and stick to Nouveau and it just happened again

Comment: I mean the error `Not starting jetty` it is marked with red asterisk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty is an open-source project providing an HTTP server, HTTP client, and javax.servlet container.

Jetty provides a Web server and javax.servlet container, plus support for SPDY, WebSocket, OSGi, JMX, JNDI, JAAS and many other integrations. These components are open source and available for commercial use and distribution.<sup>[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)</sup>

Activate it or change it to zero, if you plan on using it.

To uninstall, the best way that I would use, since I don't know how it was installed, is by using synaptic.  Just make sure you pay attention to what it removes.

Comment: can you please yet take a look to my [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422610/cannot-stop-or-restart-display-manager-due-to-java-misconfiguration-in-12-04) it's connected to this one. Thanks.